# Using a StaticResource SolidColorBrush to define the Gradient Stop Colors

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, colors, brushes

I am creating some wpf resource dictionaries with all the styles for an application! I have a few `LinearGradientBrush`es, where the color is set directly in the L`inearGradientBrush` reference as `GradientStop`s. However, I want to have a predefined set of colors that I can use a a reference for each `GradientStop`, so that changing the color scheme for the application is a matter of changing the values of the `SolidColorBrush`es:

```
<SolidColorBrush Color="#5A5A5A" x:Key="colorbrushMedium" /> 
<SolidColorBrush Color="#222222" x:Key="colorbrushDark" />  


<LinearGradientBrush>
    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource colorbrushMedium}"/>
    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource colorbrushDark}" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

With the code example above, I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot convert the value in attribute 'Color' to object of type 'System.Windows.Media.Color'. '#5A5A5A' is not a valid value for property 'Color'.
```

The line it refers to is the line where `<GradientStop Color="{StaticResource colorbrushMedium}"/>` is defined.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem:

Using Color and not SolidColorBrush..

```
<Color x:Key="colorbrushMedium">#FF5A5A5A</Color>
<Color x:Key="colorbrushDark">#FF222222</Color>
<LinearGradientBrush>
    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource colorbrushMedium}"/>
    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource colorbrushDark}" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

This seems to solve my problem!

Comment: You can even write the color defined in static class Colors instead of the hex code, e.g. Gray.

Comment: What if you also need to use the same color for properties that require a SolidColorBrush?

Answer (score 17):

Use `Binding` to reference the color both in `SolidColorBrush` and in `LinearGradientBrush`:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="stop1" Color="#FF5A5A5A"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="stop2" Color="#FF222222"/>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="gradient">
  <GradientStop Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource stop1},Path=Color}" Offset="0"/>
  <GradientStop Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource stop2},Path=Color}" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```