# Assign Color of SolidColorBrush to another SolidColorBrush

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have a DefaultInnerBorder_Normal resource from a 3rd part library and it is SolidColorBrush. I need to asign it to few of my Resources, but I cannot to something like below:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DefaultInnerBorder_Normal" Color="#FF000000"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlInnerBorder_Normal" Color="{StaticResource DefaultInnerBorder_Normal.Color"/>
```

I've seen that answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1832052/278618 of @code-zoop
but I cannot change type of DefaultInnerBorder_Normal to Color. 
Is there any option except Converter?

Comment: Removed my answer - didn't see the part with the 3rd party library...
Does that color change often? Because otherwise you could just grab that color and define your own `SolidColorBrush` using that. What I want to say: Is it worth the effort to "bind" that color or would a "one time effort" in hardcoding the color also do the trick?

Comment: that color changes often, because user can change a theme. This DefaultInnerBorder_Normal is from 3rd party library.